# Spring autowired annotation in liferay 7.2

Tags: java, spring, autowired, liferay-7

**Hi everyone**

I want to use spring-core in liferay 7.2 with `@Autowired` annotation. So, i have next portlet

```java
package com.aimprosoft.module;

import com.aimprosoft.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.portlet.GenericPortlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SamplePortlet  extends GenericPortlet {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Override
    protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println(employeeService.toString());
    }
}
```

So, what i must to do in web.xml or in portlet.xml to set context listener of spring-core ? 
For example in web-servlet application i must to add

```xml
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actually problem was in spring version**

I used 3.2.0 which doesnt support java 8. When i switched to 4.0.0 everything become ok.

In conclusion. For usage spring core in portlet project for liferay i must:

- Add context listener into my WEB-INF/web.xml file

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

- Then in every portlet use following method to init `@Autowired` field

```java
@Override
public void init() throws PortletException {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}
```

- I have following persistence unit

```xml
<persistence-unit name="departments">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.aimprosoft.dao.model.Employee</class>
    <class>com.aimprosoft.dao.model.Department</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/departments"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

- Finally spring context looks following

```xml
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aimprosoft"/>
<bean id="departments" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="WEB-INF/persistence.xml"/>
</bean>
<bean id="textResource" class="java.util.ResourceBundle" factory-method="getBundle">
    <constructor-arg value="text_bundle"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>
```